# Django Oscar get cheapest offer

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-oscar

I'mm new to the Django Oscar framework. My problem is that when I'm adding offers to basket, it will add the first created offer to given product, not the cheapest offer.

The offer condition type is Count and benefit type is Absolute, for example:

```
{
    "id": 74,
    "type": "Absolute",
    "value": "70.00",
    "max_affected_items": 1,
    "proxy_class": "",
    "range": 54
},
{
    "id": 75,
    "type": "Absolute",
    "value": "100.00",
    "max_affected_items": 1,
    "proxy_class": "",
    "range": 55
}
```

if product has this two offers. i need to add cheapest offer, but when i used oscar builtin apply offer method it will add first object, not the cheapest one

Answer (score 1):

Oscar will not automatically find the cheapest offer for you - it applies offers in order of [priority](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/offer/abstract_models.py#L141-L143).

With the example you've provided above, where both offers have fixed discounts, you can solve this simply by setting the correct priority on the cheaper offer so that it always gets applied first.

If which offer is cheaper varies depending on what is in the basket, then that is more complicated. You would have to provide logic for handling this yourself - e.g., by overriding the `Applicator` class to specify a custom order in which offers are applied.

Comment: then i can use basket middleware to add my own logic.